# Stacking Filters Weka Explorer

Tags: classification, weka

Hi I'm new to Weka and using the explorer to try to do some text classification.

I have a training set which I have tested using the "word to string vector filter" and an "attribute selection" filter.  However I want to be able to test the classifier on unseen data and so have tried using the "supplied test set option".  After reading around I realise that the word to string vector filter has to be applied at the same time to both sets so I have used the "Filtered Classifier" option and proceeded to do this.  However I cannot seem to apply the Attribute Selection filter as well??

If I am going about this the wrong way please let me know? Or if there is an option to apply or stack multiple filters when classifying that'd be great.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to chain filters (`StringToWordVector` and `AttributeSelection`) using `MultiFilter`, they behave as a single filter you can put into a `FilteredClassifier`. Check a detailed tutorial at [Text Mining in WEKA Revisited: Selecting Attributes by Chaining Filters](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/text-mining-in-weka-revisited-selecting.html).